# Macro de Access solo funciona una vez, si se ejecuta de nuevo crashea

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, macros, microsoft-office

estoy diseñando una macro desde Access, que copie un bloque de celdas de un libro de Excel a otro, no me es posible hacerlo directamente desde Excel por algunos temas de uso, pero al ejecutarla por primera vez funciona correctamente, termina cierro los documentos y trato de ejecutarla de nuevo y me arroja el siguiente error

[image: Error]

El error lo marca en la siguiente linea

"FG2.ActiveSheet.Range("L15", Range("L15").End(xlDown)).Copy FL2.Worksheets("Solicitud").Cells(FilL2 + 1, 12)"

Y si cierro los documentos y ejecuto de nuevo, vuelve a funcionar, digamos que funciona una vez si y la siguiente no

Agradeceria si alguien puede orientarme.

El codigo es el siguiente

```
Dim Ex As New Excel.Application
Dim FilG2 As Integer

Dim FG2 As Workbook
Dim FL2 As Workbook

'Abriendo los documentos y estableciendo las conexiones
Ex.Workbooks.Open ("C:\Auto\Plantillas\Actualizable\G2.xlsx")
Set FG2 = Ex.Workbooks("G2.xlsx")
Ex.Workbooks.Open ("C:\Auto\Plantillas\Actualizable\L2.xlsx")
Set FL2 = Ex.Workbooks("L2.xlsx")
Ex.Visible = True

'Contando cuantas filas tiene la columna para saber donde debe pegar
FL2.Activate

FilL2 = FL2.ActiveSheet.Range("L15").End(xlDown).Row

'Copiando y pegando
FG2.Activate

FG2.ActiveSheet.Range("L15", Range("L15").End(xlDown)).Copy FL2.Worksheets("Solicitud").Cells(FilL2 + 1, 12)

Ex.Application.CutCopyMode = False


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

No he hecho pruebas, pero tu código actual cada vez que se ejecuta, crea una **nueva** instancia de Excel. La primera vez que lo ejecutas, abre los archivos, copia y termina. Pero la segunda vez, ejecuta una segunda instancia, e intenta abrir archivos que ya están abiertos en la primera instancia de Excel, y eso podría ser la razón.

Procura siempre limpiar todas las variables de objeto, así como cerrar instancias abiertas si vas a volver a usar los mismos archivos (como en este caso).

Prueba así, a ver si te puede servir:

```
Dim Ex As New Excel.Application
Dim FilG2 As Integer

Dim FG2 As Workbook
Dim FL2 As Workbook

'Abriendo los documentos y estableciendo las conexiones

Set FG2 = Ex.Workbooks.Open("C:\Auto\Plantillas\Actualizable\G2.xlsx")
Set FL2 = Ex.Workbooks.Open("C:\Auto\Plantillas\Actualizable\L2.xlsx")

Ex.Visible = True

'Contando cuantas filas tiene la columna para saber donde debe pegar
FL2.Activate

FilL2 = FL2.ActiveSheet.Range("L15").End(xlDown).Row

'Copiando y pegando
FG2.Activate

FG2.ActiveSheet.Range("L15", Range("L15").End(xlDown)).Copy FL2.Worksheets("Solicitud").Cells(FilL2 + 1, 12)

'cerramos libros.
FL2.Close True 'true para salvar cambios
FG2.Close False 'no hemos hecho cambios, cerramos sin guardar
Ex.Application.CutCopyMode = False

'limpiamos variables
Set FG2 = Nothing
Set FL2 = Nothing
Ex.Quit 'cerramos Excel
Set Ex = Nothing
```